# I want to get the all the tr id values using a checkbox and Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a accordion table and I want to get the all the id values of tr using jquery

```
<div id="acc22" class="accBox">
  <p class="accordianHead">
    <div class="accordianBody">
      <form id="form_22" action="" method="post" encoding="">
        <div style="display:none;">
          <table id="item_tbl_22" class="accTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <thead class="greyBg paddingHead">
            <tbody>

              <tr id="S3639-1-1_824" style=" ">
              <tr id="S3639-1-2_824" style=" ">
              <tr id="S3639-1-3_824" style=" ">
              <tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
      </form>
    </div>
```

How to get the id value of tr using jquery

Comment: What do you mean by "*it wasn't successful*"? Incidentally you have invalid HTML, the `<input>` elements must be wrapped in `<td>` or `<th>` elements if you want them inside a `<table>` and those elements must be wrapped in `<tr>` elements. What jQuery did you try (`each()` does nothing by itself, and tells us nothing of your attempt)?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: Those <input> elements are hidden fields so there is no impact to the result of the table. when I try to get id the value of using checkboxes it always gives me the last row value.what I want to know is how to traverse the tr value using jquery each function

Comment: You haven't even explained exactly what you are searching for. Also there are no checkboxes shown in question. Question is sadly lacking in a properly written problem description that also includes expected results

Answer (score 1):

This way you can create an array of your tr id's using jQuery.

```js
var idArray = [];
$('table#item_tbl_22 > tbody > tr').each(function() {
  if($(this).prop('id')) {
  idArray.push($(this).prop('id'));
  }
  });
console.log(idArray);
// Same result Using jQuery map() as well
var idArray_1 = [];
$('table#item_tbl_22 > tbody > tr').map(function() {
 if($(this).prop('id')) {
  idArray_1.push($(this).prop('id'));
}
});
console.log(idArray_1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="acc22" class="accBox">
  <p class="accordianHead">
    <div class="accordianBody">
      <form id="form_22" action="" method="post" encoding="">
        <div style="display:none;">
          <table id="item_tbl_22" class="accTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <thead class="greyBg paddingHead">
            <tbody>
              <input id="cloth_id22" type="hidden" value="72" name="fabric_id">
              <input id="cloth_colour_id22" type="hidden" value="824" name="data[Cloth][cloth_id]">
              <tr id="S3639-1-1_824" style=" ">
              <tr id="S3639-1-2_824" style=" ">
              <tr id="S3639-1-3_824" style=" ">
              <tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Might consider using `map()` instead

Comment: ok, but I have table item_tbl_1 to item_tbl_22 item_tbl_nth so I want to keep the values in hidden field and access with them checkboxes.item_tbl_ is dynamic value.how to do that? assign a value <?php $id; ?> something like this?